# Use custom template on custom post type

Tags: php, child-theme, genesis-theme-framework, framework

So I'm kinda stuck on something that I'm trying to achieve and unsure how to even target it, so below I will explain all that I have and what I have tried.

So I'm using the Genesis Framework and a child theme. I'm trying not to touch the Framework or the child theme, and do all the development inside mu-plugins but I'm having trouble targeting a custom template.

So I've created a custom post type that is linked as `/profile/` so let's say I create a file called `page-profile.php`, following WordPress hierarchy it will use my custom page first.

But how do I target a template that has a URL such as `/profile/jake-ferguson/` where the author's name will be different each time?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to add a template within the theme, name your file `single-profile.php` and that will apply to all single "profile" CPTs.

But you mentioned you don't want to touch the child theme. You could instead create a plugin and use a `page_template` filter to use your plugin's `single-profile.php` template instead of any of the theme templates.

You would create a plugin folder, put your `single-profile.php` file in that folder, and add a `plugin.php` file that contains something like

```
<?php
add_action('page_template', 'wpse_apply_profile_template');
function wpse_apply_profile_template() {
    // If this is the CPT we're looking for
    if(is_singular('profile')) {
        // Apply this plugin's "single-profile.php" template
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ . 'single-profile.php';
    }
    // Always return, even if we didn't change the template
    return $page_template;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help @WebElaine, if my structure is as the image I just uploaded above, how would I structure that?

Comment: `$page_template = dirname( __FILE__ _ . 'templates/single-profile.php';`

That should do it.

Comment: Which of the files in your screenshot is the template? `profile-card.php`?